# Why are these gaps arising in R graphs?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I am having this error every other column is filling up but except this one ?

```
data=read.csv("data.csv")
     attach(data)
     data$marks<- factor(data$marks, levels = data$marks[order(data$a)])
     c.data=melt(data, id.var="marks")
     n.data = ddply(c.data,.(marks), transform, pos = cumsum(value) - 0.5*value)

plot = ggplot(n.data, aes(x = marks, y = value)) + 
         geom_bar(stat = "identity",aes(fill = variable)) +
         geom_text(aes(label = value, y = pos), size = 3, face="bold", 
                   colour="white") +
         scale_fill_manual(values=c("#800000","#000000")) + 
         scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100), breaks=seq(0,100, by = 10)) + 
         theme(axis.line = element_line(), 
               axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60,hjust=1,colour="white"), 
               axis.text.y=element_text(colour="white"),
               axis.title.x = element_blank(),
               axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
               panel.background = element_blank(), 
               axis.ticks=element_blank()) + 
         labs(fill="")
```

This is the code I have used

```
Marks   a   b
1   49  51
2   53  47
3   54  46
4   54  46
5   55  45
6   55  45
7   55  45
8   55  45
9   55  45
10  56  45
11  56  45
12  56  44
13  56  44
14  56  44
15  56  44
16  56  44
17  57  44
18  57  43
19  57  43
20  58  42
21  58  42
22  59  41
23  60  40
24  60  40
25  61  39
26  61  39
27  61  39
28  62  38
29  62  38
30  62  38
31  64  36
32  64  36
33  67  33
34  71  29
```

This is the sample data which is used i have rounded the points so that it gets to whole number

Comment: Sorry for the mistake :(

Comment: And make it the actual data...which is likely where the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original data you provided in question several rows have sum of `a` and `b` columns higher than 100.

```
apply(df,1,function(x) sum(x[2:3]))
 [1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 101 101 100 100 100 100 100 101 100
[19] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

So when you plot your data after melting and then set `limits=` inside `scale_y_continuous()` those values that exceed 100 are removed from the plot.

```
+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100), breaks=seq(0,100, by = 10))
```

Solution for this is to correct your data to have sum of `a` and `b` in all rows equal to 100 or remove `limits=c(0,100)` from the `scale_y_continuous()` and add `coord_cartesian()` - this will zoom your plot to limits.

```
+coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))
```

Comment: should i remove  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100), breaks=seq(0,100, by = 10))  this code completely and add coor_cartesian code?

Comment: @Zack no, just remove limits=c(0,100). Argument breaks= can remain inside scale_y_continuous(). About ggplot2 error - there are no function ggplot2(). Function name is ggplot().

Comment: Error: could not find function "coor_cartesian"
this is the error now

Comment: @Zack Sorry, should be coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))  Updated also answer

Comment: Thank you soo much for the reply :) I really appreciate your effort